# use image as background or create CSS, pros and cons

Tags: html, css

I am working on a HTML5 mobile application using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap. It will be deployed on multiple platforms.

I got a banner png below:

[image]

My questions are:

1)  Directly use this image as background or use CSS to dynamically generate one, which way is better? ( in terms of speed of the app and user experience)

2)  If CSS is a better way, how to make the height of the banner dynamically grow with the text contents inside the banner? (not sure how to handle the decorations)

any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You might look into SVG to get the best look that scales beautifully with the least file size: http://caniuse.com/svg though it will be more complex to set up initially.

Answer (score 0):

1) CSS would technically, probably, be the more efficient method simply because that is purely code and it wouldn't have to reference another file. However, I don't feel as if that gain in efficiency is enough to worry about to put yourself through the bother of having to recreate something similar in CSS. In other words, just use the image file. PhoneGap is used for HTML. Images are common in HTML files, so I wouldn't worry about it.

2) Maybe I'm not understanding what exactly you're asking, but shouldn't you just be able to use padding?

```
<div style = "background-color: red; padding: 25px;"> Banner Text </div>
<!-- Don't use this type of styling in practice, it's bad technique. -->
```

Hope this answered your question.

Comment: will he be able to use padding? this is not a repeatable image, so what happens when content exceeds the height of the image? (I have 0 idea about mobile app development, so I don't know if there's any chance of that actually happening).

Comment: That's what I'm confused about, honestly. I don't know what exactly his expectations would be if he were to try to do the CSS option. The phrase "use CSS to dynamically generate one" infers, to me, that it wouldn't be trying to necessarily copy this image. Therefore, the content exceeding the height of the image shouldn't be an issue, as the image wouldn't be a factor in that option.

Comment: well, may be he was talking about actually creating the border with css, like css shapes (I saw a post somewhere where the author made an entire array of shapes using pure css), then I guess padding won't matter.